# How can a title be placed for a group of pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Using the `groupplots` library in `pgfplots`, how can a title be set for a group of plots?  The following code (basically from the manual) is an example layout.  I don't want each plot to have a title, but rather a title be placed centered on top of the group.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      {group size=2 by 2}},
    height=3cm,width=3cm,
    title={Title}]

    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample groupplot]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a TikZ node as a title for a quick solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=3cm,width=3cm]
    \nextgroupplot[title=One]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Two]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Three]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Four]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
  \end{groupplot}
\node (title) at ($(group c1r1.center)!0.5!(group c2r1.center)+(0,2cm)$) {THE Title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since I don't intend on having individual plot titles, I used `\node (title) at ($(group c1r1.north)!0.5!(group c2r1.north)$) [above, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]` to simulate how pgfplots places the title using `axis description cs`.

Comment: @sappjw Yep, that's a neat solution.

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of this part? `($(group c1r1.center)!0.5!(group c2r1.center)+(0,2cm)$)` Thanks.

Comment: @Cebri It is the `calc` library syntax. It means find the halfway between center anchors of those given nodes.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `\matrix` command to group plots together inside of a single `tickzpicture`, and add the title to the created tickzpicture:

```
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{small}
    \matrix {
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
        &
        % differently large labels are aligned automatically:
        \begin{axis}[ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$},ylabel style={font=\Huge}]
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        %
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,xlabel style={font=\Huge}]
            \addplot {x^3};
        \end{axis}
        &
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^4};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

(the title isn't added here but you just need to add it on top of the matrix command)
More information about the `PGFPLOTS` package in the [PGFPlot Manual](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/pgfplots.pdf).