# How do I access the code that underlies a specific LaTeX package command?

Tags: sourcecode

For instance, `\legend` in a `pgfplots` bar chart. But in general, it would help as well.

In this particular case because I'm [trying to build a legend outside an `axis` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685283/graph-legend-is-shared-by-two-subfigures-how-can-i-make-sure-it-overlays-the-se).

I was hoping there'd be a better way than to go trawling through all of GitHubs folders.

Comment: `\show\command` but when I tried it with `\legend` it came up as undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \the, \showthe and \show commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345185/difference-between-the-showthe-and-show-commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general answer:

You can always retrieve its .sty or .cls file on your system, or from the ctan repository, and inspect the file, well best its copy. Use your favorite ASCII editor with useful syntax highlighting.

Also, many packages describe their code in detail by mixing code with documentation.

Be prepared to go through long files.